# Is there a way to use Asian language input methods from pre-Windows 8 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Okay, so several years ago I bought the language learning software Transparent™ Language Premium Edition Japanese, but for reasons I never got around to using it till now.

Turns out, because Windows changed something about how the Asian languages are input or something, the software won't work. So unless I want to install a pirated version of a prehistoric Windows OS on a virtual machine, it seems I'm out of luck.

If anyone has any idea how to work around the problem, I would be super grateful.

Link to FAQ at Transparent™'s website: http://support.transparent.com/?p=154

Comment: What's "pre Win8" mean exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound It means from the Windows operating systems predating Windows 8. :)

Comment: Someone downvoted my question, so I assume I did something wrong. If the person who downvoted me would be so kind as to tell me what exactly I did wrong as well, it could even be constructive criticism. After all, I can't fix a problem I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you would have to install a third-party pre-windows 8 compatible software that will input japanese characters. Something like the on-screen keyboard but for japanese.

Comment: That's a good idea, and the flash card software that was bundled with Transparent (Byki) actually has an on screen keyboard that I was able to use to practise the vocabulary. Not sure if it will work with the main software, but so far it seems promising. :)